# Determine when user purchased iPhone application

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is it possible to determine when a user first purchased your application? (Not just when they last downloaded it, hopefully device independent)

Comment: That information would only be obtainable from the user's iTunes account.

Comment: Seems that there could be no way currently to do this, but I'll leave the question open in hopes that I might get notified if this functionality is added :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the first run into the NSUserDefaults, the only problem with this approach is if they delete and reinstall the App you would lose the data:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"FirstRun"];
```

Comment: Also, there is no way to get that information off.

Comment: True, I guess the question doesn't state whether this is to be in the sandbox of the application or to be stored elsewhere.

Comment: This will provide First Run, looking for Purchased date.

Comment: Currently this seems to be the closest answer, sadly doesn't solve my needs :(